# cant get my footer to stay in Row format on smaller screens

Tags: javascript, html, css

on screen sizes smaller than 768px my footer-nav does not display as row but instead as column. I have looked and I do realize that my flexbox code will not be taken into account.. so therefore I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated. Along with that I'm trying to find a way to transform my footer so that on screen sizes larger than 768px the footer will display more links on it. So far I have found no ways to do this.

```css
/* -- Base Element Styles -- */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: lightslategray;
}

h2 {
  color: lightslategray;
}

h3,
a {
  color: lightslategrey;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

p {
  padding: 8px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.unit .p {
  font-weight: 500;
}


/* -- Base Layout Styles -- */

.main-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}

main {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.name {
  font-size: 1.35em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.intro-title {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}

.main-nav {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.nav-link {
  text-align: center;
}

.main-nav a {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}

.nav-link {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.container-2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.logo {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.footer-list {
  text-align: center;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}


/* -- Layout Containers -- */

h1 a {
  padding: 0px;
}

.intro-unit,
.main-footer {
  text-align: center;
}

.intro-unit {
  color: lightslategray;
  background: wheat;
  padding: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
  margin-top: 175px;
}

.main-footer {
  color: floralwhite;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding: 14px 10px 11px 10px;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.container-2 {
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.unit {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}


/* -- Media Queries -- */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container,
  .container-2 {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .intro-unit {
    margin: 7rem auto;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .intro-unit,
  .container,
  .container-2 {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1150px;
  }
  .intro-unit {
    margin: 5rem auto;
  }
}


/* -- Flex Box -- */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .main-header,
  .main-nav,
  .intro-unit,
  .container,
  .container-2,
  .main-footer,
  .footer-nav,
  .footer-list {
    display: flex;
  }
  .main-header {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  .intro-unit {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  .container,
  .container-2 {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  .main-footer {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  .footer-list,
  .footer-nav {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .main-header {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .main-nav {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .intro-unit {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
  }
  .container,
  .container-2 {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  .footer-list {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Responsive Webpage</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main-header">
    <h1 class="name"><a href="#">Cole Smith</a></h1>
    <ul class="main-nav">
      <li class="nav-link"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-link"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li class="nav-link"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <header class="intro-unit">
    <img class="logo" src="img/profile-picture.svg" alt="profile picture">
    <div class="intro-text">
      <p>Hi, my name is Cole Smith I am an aspiring front/backend Web Designer! I am currently learning web design through Treehouse Tech and this is one of my projects.</p>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="intro-title" id="portfolio">
    <h1>Portfolio</h1>
  </div>

  <main class="container">
    <div class="unit-1 unit">
      <img src="img/marketing.svg" alt=" image representing a marketing page">
      <h2>Marketing Page</h2>
      <p>This project shows the front page of a marketing website meant for specific business i'm interested in.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="unit-2 unit">
      <img src="img/search-app.svg" alt="image representing a travel webpage design">
      <h2>Search Page</h2>
      <p>This project searches through a specific database to find information that the user is trying to look up.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="unit-3 unit">
      <img src="img/travel-app.svg" alt="image representing a favorite spot-styled webpage">
      <h2>travel app</h2>
      <p>This project compares travel times based on different transportation methods and tells you the best one.</p>
    </div>
  </main>
  <div class="container-2">
    <div class="unit-4 unit">
      <img src="img/fav-spot.svg" alt="image representing a photo gallery webpage">
      <h2>Map of Favorite Spots</h2>
      <p>This project uses mapping apis to plot points for my favorite spots in the city for a do-it-yourself walking tour.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="unit-5 unit">
      <img src="img/photo-gallery.svg" alt="image representing a calculator webpage">
      <h2>Photo Gallery</h2>
      <p>This project shows pictures from a recent trip to the viewer and allows them to easily navigate through photos.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="unit-6 unit">
      <img src="img/calculator.svg" alt="Image representing calculator-styled page">
      <h2>Calculator</h2>
      <p>Someone can enter the numbers they want and press the big blue button and get the result.</p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <footer class="main-footer">
    <div class="footer-div">
      <h3 class="footer-title">Contact</h3>
      <p id="contact">If you're interested in chatting or want more information about what i've been working on, i'd love to hear from you!</p>
      <p>Phone: 1 (303) 4040</p>
      <p>Email: cole.smith.code@gmail.com</p>
      <ul class="footer-list">
        <li class="footer-nav"><a href="#">Cole Smith</a></li>
        <li class="footer-nav"><a href="#">Back To Top</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You used min-width in your media queries which means that it only applies if the screen is bigger than 768px. if you want to use min-width, you could take everything that is in the 768px media query and write it to your normal css and when the screen size is bigger than 1024px your other media query will overwrite it.

You can read up on media queries at this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: ok thank you I will look at that article and try your suggestion!